# Trying to create .htaccess file using ftp doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to create a .htaccess file in a specific directory. I'm using Notepad++ and their plug-in for FTP (NppFTP).  I'm able to create any other files and see them in the folder but when I try to create a .htaccess I don't see that file in the directory. I get no errors, it is like nothing happened.

I tried to create this file using an FTP program and it showed the file and right away it disappeared. My guess it is because this is a special file used by the system and prefixed by a (.)

What is a way to edit that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because your ".htaccess" file is a hidden file and your system is set up to no display hidden files.

Have a look in your Notepad++ settings if there's an option to make hidden files visible/unhide.

In addition to that check the windows folder options for that option!

Answer (score 0):

switch on showing hidden files in your ftp client